# Does Selenium WebDriver for Java require some sort of IDE like Eclipse in order to run?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ide

In the Selenium Tutorial on Guru99 in the WebDriver installation tab (http://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html), one of the installation steps says to install the Eclipse IDE. I was wondering if I could get around that and just run Selenium WebDriver for Java without using any sort of IDE.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things:

1. **Designing the Selenium scripts:** Initially when you are developing your selenium script, the IDE will make job easier for you when you want to setup things, (like adding the Selenium server jar to your Reference libraries etc.)
2. **Executing the Scripts:** Once you are done with the designing of the script. Since you are using *Java*, You can export your project into a Jar (or an Executable jar) and run it directly like any other Jar file. While exporting into Jar, don't forget to choose the option of 'Export all required libraries into Jar'.

Allowing us to use a programming language, Java in this case, Selenium allows us to play around and do almost all the stuffs one can do with the Core programming language.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't require any IDE to run your selenium scripts..

however using IDE like eclipse will make your work easier and faster

Answer (score 0):

However not a requirement for Selenium, it integrates nicely with testng and with testng plugin for Eclipse, it becomes much easier to run tests. Also, if you are using Java as the language for implementing the tests, Eclipse is great tool.